# RegionFunction doesn't work with an InterpolatingFunction when using ListContourPlot

Tags: plotting, interpolation

I have a contour plot which I make using `ListContourPlot` from discrete data, which looks like this.

[image: contour plot generated from data]

The data live on grid points that are shown in light blue, and function values are not defined under the red curve; the corresponding entries are `Null`s. I believe that the diagonal 'line' running across the bottom right is an artifact of the interpolation carried out by `ListContourPlot`, and I would appreciate some help with removing that as well. I would like to exclude the region under the red line from my plot using `RegionFunction`, but I am not able to do this.

The code I am using to generate the plot shown here is as follows:

```
Show[ListContourPlot[
  Transpose@{\[Gamma]Plist10, CD2Pset10} /. {{x_, y_}, z_} -> {x, y, 
     z}, PlotTheme -> "Monochrome", PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
  ImageSize -> Medium, Mesh -> None, ClippingStyle -> Automatic, 
  RegionFunction -> 
   Function[{\[Gamma], P}, 
    Abs[P] >= Evaluate@typeCexistencefunc[\[Gamma]]]], 
 Plot[typeCexistencefunc[x], {x, 0, 0.5}, PlotStyle -> Red],ListPlot[{\[Gamma]Plist10}]]
```

The function `typeCexistencefunc` is an `InterpolatingFunction`, and you can see that it works as expected since the red line does indeed appear. However, the `RegionFunction` part does not work.

If I use a different function to define my region, such as a straight line or the equation of a circle, it works as expected.

If I do not use the `ClippingStyle` option, I get something even more strange:

[image]

Note that the only `Null`s in my data are those under the red curve. The values in the top right region of the plot are very low, and in the bottom left region of the plot they are very high.

**edited to add**: I have also tried using an unstructured interpolation function using

```
ff = Interpolation[
  Transpose@{\[Gamma]Plist10, CD2Pset10} /. {{x_, y_}, z_} -> {x, y, 
     z}]
ContourPlot[ff[\[Gamma], P], {\[Gamma], 0, 0.5}, {P, 0, 1.5}, 
 ClippingStyle -> Automatic, PlotTheme -> "Monochrome"]
```

but this doesn't work as well as a `ListContourPlot` does. The result looks like this:
[image: using interpolation function]

TL;DR: `RegionFunction` doesn't seem to work well with `ListContourPlot` when using an `InterpolatingFunction` to define the region of interest.

Comment: Have you tried to create an unstructured Interpolation function to begin was with?

Comment: You mean a 2D interpolation function? yes, I have tried `Interpolation[
 Transpose@{\[Gamma]Plist10, CD2Pset10} /. {{x_, y_}, z_} -> {x, y, 
    z}]` and tried putting that in a `ContourPlot`. The results is not much better -- I'll add it to the question

Answer (score 1):

One solution to this problem seems to be to add `Filling -> Axis, FillingStyle -> White` to my plot of the red line. This is a satisfactory workaround, but I will leave this question open in case someone has a solution to the underlying problem.